# Is there a way to keep the mesh collider when updating objects in Unity?

Tags: 3d, unity

I have a 3D object as an imported asset in Unity which i want to make updates to in Maya.
The asset get's updated automatically in Unity when i save the object in Maya - but not in the project hierarchy where i have placed it in the scene.

Is there a way to keep the object with it's mesh collider when the model is updated without having to re-create it in the hierarchy for every iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on what you're asking, but here are two suggestions anyway:

1) Have you made a prefab of this object in the scene?  Hopefully if you update the model, the prefab gets updated, so the object in the scene gets updated.

2) If that isn't what you want, you could try writing an editor script to do things for you.  Look here: http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor.OnPostprocessModel.html

Comment: Indeed, using the object as a prefab solved the problem if the prefab mesh had the property "Generate Colliders" checked.